# Past tense of the verb "FedEx"

Tags: single-word-requests, grammaticality, verbs, punctuation, past-tense

How do I write the past tense of *FedEx*?

For example:

> I **FedEx'd** the package to you yesterday.
>
> I **Fedexd** the package to you yesterday.
>
> I **FedEx-d** the package to you yesterday.

I am transcribing verbatim so I can't change the wording.

Comment: How about: "Didn't you get it yet?"

Comment: @JeffSahol - at the end of my question I mentioned that I am dealing with a verbatim transcript and therefore cannot change the wording.  Thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wiktionary suggests **[FedExed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/FedExed)**, which seems to be the most popular (see a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=fedexed#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=fedexed&pbx=1&oq=fedexed&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l51538l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c313f2edd24fc65d&biw=1366&bih=643)), but *Fedexed* and *fedexed* are also common.

Also, [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=Fedexed,fedexed,FedExed&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) illustrates a definite preference for *FedExed*:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=Fedexed%2Cfedexed%2CFedExed&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3

I would tend to go with *FedExed* because it is so popular, though I wouldn't disparage the natural *Fedexed*, or the inevitable *fedexed* (cf. *googled*, etc).  In fact, I will probably change my mind in the near future and choose *fedexed*, since it's not at all ambiguous.

As an aside, it has become uncommon for *'d* to be appended to form the past tense of a verb.  It's most often used poetically, especially archaically, because it used to be necessary to specify when the *-ed* ending was pronounced as a separate syllable.  (E.g. *severed* would have been pronounced *'se-ver-ed*, whereas *sever'd* would have been *'se-verd*.)  Needless to say, this spelling contraction is no longer necessary.

Also, "-d" has never been common; in fact I've never seen it, so I would avoid it.

Lastly, a lone *d* is only used when the last letter of the verb to be past-tensed is an *e*, (e.g. *file* becomes *filed* - added *d*, but *end* becomes *ended* - added *ed*).

Addendum: appending *ed* is the best way to create the past tense of *FedEx*, rather than a single *d*, punctuated or not.

Comment: In other words, just like xeroxed or googled, they retain the normal rules of the past tense. Note however that these words may or may not be found in dictionaries.

Comment: Definitely *fedexed*!!!

Comment: Womderful!  Now what about DHL in particular?  DHLed?  By the way, this is a fantastic answer and a lovely graph.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Jimi: I would prefer it too, for the same reason as preferring *googled* over *Googled*.  I was surprised to learn that *FedExed* is so common.

Comment: @Rachel: [DHLed](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=DHL#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22DHLed%22&pbx=1&oq=%22DHLed%22&aq=f&aqi=g-l5&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=17690l19437l1l19694l2l2l0l0l0l0l350l350l3-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=c313f2edd24fc65d&biw=1366&bih=643) is good per se, but since it's nowhere near as popular a term as *fedexed*, if at all possible, I would try to reword the sentence to avoid using it as a verb.  In a transcript, though, it shouldn't matter, since it'll be in an appropriate context.

Comment: @ drɱ65 δ: I know, beats me too. @Rachel: *DHL* as a verb in the present tense works very well. Even *UPS*, as well. Things get iffy, however, when one goes into past tense. *Fedex* is fast becoming universal, though (at least in the US), as people increasingly use it to refer to any courier service these days.

Comment: @Jimi Oke (+1):  The pronounciation of "fedexed" is intuitive, unlike with acronyms such as DHL and UPS, which could be an added factor for its popularity.  Also, FedEx is a company name that seems to have more notoriety given its history that began with amazing innovation that practically turned the entire delivery industry upside-down (shipping everything centrally to Memphis, sorting at night, and delivering the next day, mainly to resolve the infamous "lost packages" routing problems with simplicity that happened to also have the wonderful side-effect of overnight service).

Comment: @dr65 - I think it's a legal thing. If your name becomes synonymous with something (e.g. hoover and vacuum cleaners) then you loose the right to your trademark. Making sure people keep the capital 'G' or the capital 'F' and 'E', mean that it is still a branding, not a general use verb.